# Cells including an addin call do not calculate

Tags: excel, excel-addins

I have an Excel spreadsheet that includes some formulae making calls to an in-house developed excel addin.

When calculation is triggered automatically or manually by pressing F9 or clicking 'Calculate Now' call calculations are performed except for those including addin calls.

However if I click into the formula bar and hit return these cells calculate without any problem.

Why might these cells not be getting calculated?

Comment: Excel calculation only recalls cells marked as "dirty" (a cell formula is dirty if any of the cells refered to by its parameters has changed).  Are you passing _all_ dependant data as parameters to the UDF?

Comment: Maybe putting  `Application.Volatile` as the first line in the offending function definitions can do the trick. This would especially be the case if the cells are supposed to be e.g. random number generators.

Comment: Please post your UDF code: (The most likely explanation is that the UDF references cells that are not passed in as parameters).

Comment: UDF is written in C#. It is only using data passed as parameters. In any case I updated the function definition to mark it as volatile, but still no joy.